# Почему не отображается картинка в профиле пользователя?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

В базовую модель джанги, кроме обязательных полей добавил аватарку (файл-картинку) и дату
рождения. Но сейчас при заходе на сайт на локальном сервере по url

```
http://localhost:8000/tasks/list/#
```

картинка не отображается, а только квадратик файла.
 В консоли:  http://localhost:8000/media/user_avatars/2020/05/26/montage-1000by697-6d6567.png 404 (Not Found)

Почему путь не соответствует?

`pip install Pillow` - установлен и миграции сделаны

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

accounts/models.py

```js
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_avatars/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Профиль пользователя %s" % self.user.username
```

settings.py в конце дописано:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

accaunts/urls.py

```js
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from accounts import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
#from .views import SignUpView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    # path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    #path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup')
    path("edit", views.edit, name="edit")
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

accounts/admin

```js
from django.contrib import admin

from tasks.models import TodoItem


@admin.register(TodoItem)
class TodoItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('description', 'is_completed', 'created')
```

Comment: а как выводите в шаблоне страницы?

Comment: @ Vadim.Sharoikin  у меня сейчас 3 base.html 1 dir - /todoapp/tasks/templates/tasks.base.html  2 dir todoapp/templates/base.html 3 dir todoapp/templates/tasks/base.html во всех этот шаблон
 https://pastebin.com/Yw7QdtJy

Comment: а дни рождения выводятся?

Comment: в админке в профилях видны даты, пользователю на сайте - нет. Ошибка при переходе http://localhost:8000/todoapp/media/user_avatars/2020/05/26/28700682_1624501880973274_8652145277999880157_o.jpg Using the URLconf defined in todoapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

tasks/
accounts/
admin/
The current path, todoapp/media/user_avatars/2020/05/26/28700682_1624501880973274_8652145277999880157_o.jpg, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

обращение из одного app в другое не идет. если **todoapp** поменять на **accounts** то будет показывать. либо связывай их, либо templatetags в помощь